# AutoCompleteTextView that triggers on "@"

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, textview, chatroom

I have a chatroom Android app that I am making and I have a list of users that I would like to be autocompleted in the text view when there is an "@" typed.

So when a user types @ I would like a drop down of the users in the room to appear but only once the @ is typed.

How do I do this? Any solution would help, even not using an AutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a MultiAutocompleteTextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html

Here's a Tokenizer I used for the same purpose. I use a custom Span to denote a profile tag called ProfileTagSpan, which is necessary because I need to display the profile name to the user but save the profile ID in the string. Yours could be simpler if this is not necessary.

```
public class ProfileTagTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

    /*
     * Search back from cursor position looking for @ symbol
     * If none found then cancel filtering by making the constraint length 0
     * Also cancel if another tag found as tags can't overlap
     */
    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        for (int i = cursor; i > 0; i--) {
            if (text.charAt(i - 1) == '@') return i;
            else if (text instanceof Spanned &&
                    ((Spanned) text).getSpans(i, i, ProfileTagSpan.class).length > 0) break;
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    /*
     * Use the cursor position for token end as we have no delimiter on the tag
     */
    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        return cursor;
    }

    /*
     * Add a space after the tag
     */
    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
            i--;
        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            return text;
        }
        else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            }
            else {
                return text + " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOAH! That's confusing. So I have a list of strings; userList and a MultiAutocompleteTextView: editComplete... How do I do what I was trying to, I don't need anything like IDs... just when you click @ for the list of users to pop up

Comment: The only difference between this and an AutocompleteTextView is the Tokenizer. It defines where a token starts and ends so that the widget knows when to show the popup and what to pass to the adapter as a filter. Are you familiar with standard AutocompleteTextViews and adapters? Is it just the tokenizer that you find confusing?